# appcelerator multiple channels for push notifications

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator

According to the docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications-method-notify

> channel : String/String[] required

Name of the channel. For multiple channels, either comma-separate the list of channels or use an array of strings.

The name of the push channel cannot start with a hash symbol ('#') or contain a comma (',').

However, I have a user subscribed to both "cats" and "dogs" channels, and am trying to push to both channels at once. I've tried several different syntaxes, including the most like the description of:

curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -F 'channel=dogs,cats' -F "to_ids=everyone" -F "payload=test dogs & cats" https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/push_notification/notify.json?key=XXX

400 Error - "Subscription not found"

Does anyone have this working & can share the correct syntax on it?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your question I have the same problem but with the `notify_tokens` method.

I am not sure it is the right procedure, but I opened question [29366000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366000/appcelerator-push-notifications-with-notify-tokens-to-multiple-channels) that might interest you since it contains some more examples.

I hope someone would help us in solving the problem, in the meanwhile I do:

```
for channel in channels:
  ... POST to AppCelerator notify_tokens (or notify) channel by channel
```

this is not a great hassle for me today, but it could be in future when channels number will increase.